# Classifying text field 'B' using integer in field 'A'?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, function

I wrote an if elif statement that will loop through records (field A) and populate a new field (field B) based on A's contents.

Field A name is 'CLASS'. Field B is 'class_desc'.

```
reclass(!class_desc!,!CLASS!)
def reclass(class_desc, CLASS):
 if CLASS == '100':
  return "100 - Agricultural"
 if CLASS == '105':
  return "105 - Agricultural Vacant Land (Productive)"
 elif CLASS == '110':
  return "110 - Livestock and Products"
 elif CLASS == '111':
  return "111 - Poultry and Poultry Products: eggs, chickens, turkeys, ducks and geese"
 elif CLASS == '112':
```

This 'completes successfully' but does not fill field B.

What am I doing wrong?

Obviously there is something fundamental that I cant get through my head about functions syntax.

Comment: It's possible you've created the field with a numeric type, but you're trying to insert text. In this case it just won't enter the value into the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'100' is text, 100 is integer so

```
 if CLASS == '100':
```

will never be true if CLASS field is of integer type.
Change to:

```
 if CLASS == 100:
```

And you dont need to include class_desc since you dont use it in the function. You can also use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and save some typing:

```
def reclass(CLASS):
    d = {100:"100 - Agricultural", 105:"105 - Agricultural Vacant Land (Productive)", 110:"110 - Livestock and Products", 111:"111 - Poultry and Poultry Products: eggs, chickens, turkeys, ducks and geese"}
    if CLASS in d:
        return d[CLASS]
    else:
        return "Class not found"
```

Call the function on field class_desc with:

```
reclass(!CLASS!)
```